# How to not get datepicker to clear text field values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a website that looks like [image: this]

where "Begin Date" and "End Date" are [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

When generating the webpage I can fill in values in those fields, but adding datepicker to them as well, clears the values.

I initialize datepicker like so

```
$(function() {
    var dates = $("#from, #to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                selectedDate, instance.settings);
            dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
        }
    });


    $("#from, #to").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm-yy");
});
```

and the HTML looks like

```
<input class="new" type="text" id="from" name="from"/>
```

How do I get datepicker to not clear the form field values when the webpage is loaded?

Comment: Are you sure it's the datepicker clearing the values? I've never had that happen before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know exactly why but it has to do with your `onSelect` function. I think you're expecting a special `dateFormat` and, given that your initial value doesn't have that format, datepicker just *drops* the value.

If you, however, set the `dateFormat` initially matching the initial value of your input, you won't have any problem.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/3MG9D/